# Twitter bootstrap typeahead unable to add to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, function, jquery-events

Is there a way to convert twitter bootstrap's typeahead function into a `$("body").on()` function? The following code works fine if the element exists on the page load.

```
$("#job_title").typeahead({
    source: searchFunction,        
    onselect: function(obj) {            
    }
});
```

But if I add the text input with `id="job_title"` dynamically, the above function doesn't work.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Fix the missing quote before someone thinks that's the problem

Comment: Oops, yeah that was just a bad paste error.  Thanks for pointing that out. but this is not the issue :)

Comment: Is it a problem to initialize the `typeahead` on the element when you add it?

Comment: Nope, this code works perfectly if the #job_title element is already on the page inside the HTML.  This code only does not work if I dynamically add the #job_title element.

Comment: I was referring to the point in code where you add the job title element. When you add it dynamically you might as well call `typeahead` on it as well.

Comment: Hmm... well, after I call the above block of code, I also call this: if ($("#" + inputBoxId).length > 0) {
        $("#" + inputBoxId).data("typeahead").source = searchFunction;
    }

Comment: I am definitely re-calling this function immediately after I add the new input element to the page.

Comment: You need to add the code how you create the element and consequently call `.typeahead` on it. Because http://jsfiddle.net/9DxLZ/1/ is working just fine.

Comment: I think I'm actually already doing that.  I'm adding the #job_title element to the page dynamically, and then immediately calling the above code.  As I mentioned before, on a pre-existing element, the above code works without any issues.

Comment: On this simple jsFiddle, I'm not seeing the input box react to the typing, since there are no potential result values there. I'm hoping I'm being clear on the issue.

Comment: It does react, you have to type `h` because the source only has `"hello"`...

Comment: Ah, I see.  Alright, I think this is probably going to work.  Off to an meeting now but eager to try this when I return.

Comment: Is the accepted answer the only way of accomplishing this? While Esailija's fiddle works, this may not be ideal for similar elements that are already created. For instance, using Esailija's fiddle example, what if that input was already created, then another was dynamically created? This means `.typeahead` must be binded twice, once on doc ready and another when the element is dynamically created to cover both types of generated inputs. Is there a way to bind `.typeahead` once (beyond the accepted answer)?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I was the one who answered my own question. Try to reach out to Esailija if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded [jquery.livequery.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/downloads) to get the behavior I wanted:

```
$("#job_title").livequery("create", function() {
    $(this).typeahead({
        source: searchFunction,        
        onselect: function(obj) {            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find an alternate way of accomplishing this without using supplemental JavaScript?

Comment: I actually recently swapped out the bootstrap implementation for the jQuery-ui implementation due to browser compatibility issues.

Comment: What browser compatibility issues did you run into?

Comment: IE8 was an issue for me, I believe.  It struggles with a lot of stuff, but we need to be IE8 compatible for our customers.

Answer (score 3):

This solution requires no additional javascript. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094730

```
$("#element-that-will-contain-typeaheads").on("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
    $(this).find(".typeahead").typeahead();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fx = {
    "init":function() {
        $("#id_of_an_element").typeahead({
            minLength:2,
            delay:1 ...
        })
    },
    "method2":function(){
        some content;
    }
}
```

Every time the element containing the typeahead is loaded into the DOM (eg. via AJAX success, call fx.init();