# Add a listener to an element that is dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a javascript/jQuery page where I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's typeahead.  There are two separate places in the javascript where I add elements that I would like to be typeaheads.  Without asking for subjective answers, what's a good way for me to register the inputs as typeaheads dynamically?  Give them all different ID's and register every time I add them? Is there any magic that can be done with `.on()`?

Comment: Are the elements constructed with DOM methods (`.createElement`, etc) or by String and `.innerHTML`/`.html()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` delegation to do that. For example:

```
$("#element-that-will-contain-typeaheads").on("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
    $(this).find(".typeahead").typeahead();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work however, as it's not a listener.  The `.typeahead` is a register, and as I understand it, cannot be in `.on()`.

Comment: There is an event for when DOM nodes are inserted, let me edit my answer

Comment: Should I care that I might be "reregistering" `.typeahead` ?

Comment: jQuery plugins usually check if the plugin was already registered before registering it, so there's nothing to worry about. I'm sure the twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin does it as well.

Comment: Isn't DOMNodeInserted deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FMutation_events

Answer (score 0):

the most simplest way, that will work for `typeahead, datepicker etc`

First you need to understand how you are adding input elements that you want to apply `bootstrap typeahead`

to add elements try to achieve something like below:

```
 //add this in your add button click handler
 $tinput = $('<input type="text" name="bootstrap" class="typeahead"/>');

 //apply bootstrap typeahead
 $tinput.typeahead();
```

this way it will work, I thought sharing here would help others :)