# How do you use typeahead on live elements?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

Using [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

Normally you would use it like `$(element).typeahead({ ... })`, but how do you use it on "live" elements?

```
$(parent).on('typeahead', element, function() { ??? });
```

Comment: Check here  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037322/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-unable-to-add-to-dynamically-created-element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it by creating one function attaching `typeahead` to the element. I then used this function on pageload and after adding a new element.

```
function addTypeaheadToInput(input) {
    $(input).typeahead(...);
}
```

Running this on pageload:

```
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('[name*="[search]"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    addTypeaheadToInput(inputs[i]);
}
```

Then call that function every time I add a new element:

```
form.querySelector('#add_new_row').onclick = function() {
    var tr = newrow(); // A function to create a new table row containing our input element.

    addTypeaheadToInput(tr.querySelector('[name*="[search]"]'));
}
```